# Failed to pass array to PDO prepared statement after decoded from JSON array

Tags: php, function, class, pdo, prepared-statement

**Please see update at the bottom for latest info!**

I failed to use the data that is first json encoded then decoded afterward. the variable in the array somehow is not recognized by the PDO prepared statement. The `$user` is passed successfully, but when `execute`, all the variables just seem all vanished and become `NULL`. What is the part that went wrong?

**Code:**

```
class User {

    private $dbh;
    public function updateValue($user){     
        try{
            $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE eq_question SET ". $user->field ."=? WHERE questID=?");

            $sth->execute(array($user->newvalue, $user->id));

            echo "|||SPACE|||Now its time to use it, they become... ";
            echo "user->newvalue-";
            var_dump( $user->newvalue);
            echo "user->id-";
            var_dump( $user->id);
            echo "EXECUTED RESULT---";

            var_dump( $sth->errorInfo());
            echo "SUCCESS!";
        }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    };
        return json_encode(1);  

    }
}
//Troubleshooters//////////Troubleshooters///////////////Troubleshooters////////////////Troubleshooters



$user = new stdClass;
$userParams = array('id' => 1, 'field' => 'questTitle', 'newvalue' => "Baaaaa");
$user = json_encode(array("user"=>$userParams));
echo " |||SPACE||| BEFORE DECODE-  ";
var_dump($user);
$user = json_decode($user);
echo " |||SPACE||| AFTER DECODE-  ";
var_dump($user);
$userN=new User(...); 
$dump=$userN->updateValue($user);
print($dump);
var_dump($dump);
```

**Returned Result:**

```
|||SPACE||| BEFORE DECODE- string(58) "{"user":{"id":1,"field":"questTitle","newvalue":"Baaaaa"}}" 
|||SPACE||| AFTER DECODE- object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["user"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["field"]=> string(10) "questTitle" ["newvalue"]=> string(6) "Baaaaa" } } 
|||SPACE||| INSIDE updateValue, the user is like this: object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["user"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["field"]=> string(10) "questTitle" ["newvalue"]=> string(6) "Baaaaa" } } 
|||SPACE|||BEFORE START USING THEM...NULL NULL 
|||SPACE||| Now its time to use it, they become...user->newvalue-NULL user->id-NULL EXECUTED RESULT---array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "42000" [1]=> int(1064) [2]=> string(170) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=NULL WHERE questID=NULL' at line 1" } SUCCESS! 
|||SPACE||| PRINT----- 1 
|||SPACE||| VAR_DUMP----- string(1) "1"
```

**Update**

**I found that the $user array DID passed into the function, but can not access individual variable at all. Could anyone inform me what could be the cause?**

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if there is any info missing that any of you need to resolve it? Because I still can not find a answer yet... kinda frustrating -_-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a key of a json\_decoded array return NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383568/calling-a-key-of-a-json-decoded-array-return-null)